# Rundeck API with LDAP Auth - 401 Authorization Required

Tags: api, rundeck

I am attempting to connect to the Rundeck API using CURL but I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error:

```
curl --insecure --location --request GET 'https://rundeck.example.com' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: xyz'
```

> 401 Authorization Required
>
> ## Authorization Required
>
> This server could not verify that
>   you are authorized to access the document requested.  Either you
>   supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser
>   doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
>
> ---
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (Oracle) Server at rundeck.example.com Port
>   80

If I try it using my username, it works.

```
curl --insecure --location -u 123456789 -p password --request GET 'https://rundeck.example.com' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: xyz'
```

I created the auth token on Rundeck using my personal user that has admin privileges.

Please note that I have set up LDAP at web server level (httpd.conf) and control user access from there.

Answer (score 0):

To access API you need to specify some action (for example: run a job, get metrics, etc.)

For example, get the instance metrics:

```
curl --location --request GET "http://yourhost:4440/api/34/metrics/metrics" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: C8nVU5AhdzpQ8ucBeMG1ITFvSfaKCw6u"
```

[Here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k?version=latest) you have a lot of examples.

Comment: It gives me the same error - `401 Authorization Required`. I may be generating the token incorrectly? When I click "Generate new token" on the profile page, it asks me to enter **User** and **Roles**. What is exactly expected here?

Comment: Fill that if you want to create a token for another user (as admin of course), if your leave that text boxes by default, Rundeck creates the token for the current user using current groups/roles. Maybe you are passing an old/wrong token?

Comment: I just created this token but getting the same error. I have set up LDAP for general authorization to Rundeck on Apache web server (httpd.conf). Apologies for sounding naive, but can that be blocking the requests?

Comment: Don't worry :-) keep in mind that Rundeck needs to get the LDAP users/roles in this way: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#configuration

Comment: This was exactly the issue. I have not set up LDAP in the way mentioned in the resource that you pointed. I have simply set up LDAP on Apache web server that controls the Authentication and Authorization is controlled at Rundeck level.